# How to query for object properties of individuals using OWL DL Query

Tags: owl, protege, dlquery

Say I have a relationship between two individuals such that "Bob works for MiningCo."

I want to be able to ask it "Who does Bob work for?" but it seems like in OWL DL the only question I know how to to write is "Who works for MiningCo?" i.e.

```
worksFor some {MiningCo}
```

Is there a way to ask a question where I can get an individual object when I query with a individual subject and a predicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DL queries are Manchester syntax class expressions. Manchester syntax is a user-friendly syntax for OWL ontologies. OWL allows to define inverse properties. Thus:

```
inverse worksFor some {Bob}
```

> Is there a way to ask a question where I can get an individual object when I query with a individual subject and a predicate?

You could also use the SPARQL plugin or the Snap SPARQL plugin:

```
SELECT * WHERE {:Bob :worksFor ?object}
```

The difference is that the latter supports querying over inferred knowledge.

Comment: Kralin, you have came to the rescue again!  Much thanks.